# Automatically move data from Hbase to Redis

Tags: java, apache, redis, hbase, jedis

I am working in java and I want to move all Hbase data to Redis using a library that should automatically do this work after some specified time interval. Is there any such kind of library that can do this kind of stuff?

Comment: What do you mean by move? Transfer all the data from one to the other so you no longer use HBase?... You would have to implement that yourself.

Comment: No, I want to use Hbase as backup and data should be migrated to redis after every week. But Hbase should also have data. So, when redis is down due to any problem then I will be accessing data from Hbase.